# Angular material setting color primary, accent, warn

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I've recently started using angular material and I'm slightly confused how to set colors for specific elements. 
I am importing the Angular theme `indigo-pink.css` as a tester.

when using a mat button I have the following

```
<button mat-flat-button color="primary">Test</button>
```

Which adds the correct primary color to the button.

I have added 2 different elements as well, a span and a mat-card as shown below.

```
<span color="primary">Test Span</span>
<mat-card color="primary">Simple card</mat-card>
```

Essentially I would like this to be the same color as the button, but it's not being implemented. 
Is there a way to include these elements to have the primary colors included without having to manually add it into css?

Thanks

Comment: using bootstrap maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I will go with yes and no. Because the color attribute is not natively supported by span or mat-card. But by creating a new attribute directive you can basically extend their behavior.

I created a really basic directive [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pv7k4h), you can basically extend it for your needs.

Comment: Seems like a good idea to use. But then what's the point of using an angular material theme when they give you the primary, accents, and warning colors when I'm going to define another color in the directive? 
Is there a way to pull in the angular material color(s) into the directive?

Comment: Yes there is. When you define a button with color=primary for example, it will add  "mat-primary" class to button. In the directive, Instead of changing the style you can add new class to the element.